# strong parameters not accepting array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have this in my view which is a multiselect checkbox

**Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_roles, :allow_destroy => true
  has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles
end
```

**view**

```
<%= check_box_tag 'user[role_ids][]', role.id, user.blank? ? nil : user.roles.include?(role) ,id: dom_id(role)%>
```

**the strong parameters for this is written as**

```
  def user
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name,{:role_ids => []})
  end
```

But on create it says

```
Processing by Admin::UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+y8iWya5KIILqS0embEUEZuClycXq0O9Q4pA+MnbM0g=", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "email"=>"a@loclahost.com", "language"=>"en", "access_level_id"=>"1", "role_ids"=>["", "1", "", "5", "", "", ""], "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create user"}

Unpermitted parameters: role_ids
Unpermitted parameters: role_ids
Unpermitted parameters: role_ids
Unpermitted parameters: role_ids
```

Any clue why is it not accepting the array of role_ids which is coming from form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering myself, I got it working not directly, but the below method from the [Strong Parameters issues discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454) helped me in converting a normal parameter to a whitelisted one.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted[:role_ids] = params[:user][:role_ids]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 21):

See the Rails [Strong Parameters documentation regarding nested attributes](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters).

The correct format is:

```
params.permit(:name, {:roles => []}, ...)
```

<strike>[AnkitG's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17880288/2631472) worked for me in Rails 4 using the [Role Model](https://github.com/martinrehfeld/role_model) gem for my user model. My user controller's implementation of _params ended up looking like:</strike>

```
def user_params
  # Bug with permit for nested arrays... @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17880288/2631472
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :middle_name).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted[:roles] = params[:user][:roles]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

This should work

```
params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :role_ids => [])
```

Comment: paste your create method pls

Comment: created a GIST [here](https://gist.github.com/ankit8898/6088035) . Please have a look

Comment: can you post error message when you do it this way? I tried it in the console and it works correctly (using the parameters in your question)

Comment: How do I specify role_ids as a separate key?