# Getting ForbiddenAttributesError while passing an array of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having issues with Rails 4 Strong Parameters. The thing is I try to pass some parameters that look like this and it raises a ForbiddenAttributesError exception afterwards:

```
"survey_answer"=>{"a1"=>"answer_1",
 "a2"=>"answer_1",
 "a3"=>"answer_3",
 "a4"=>["test1",
 "test2",
 "test3"],
 "a7"=>"answer_7",
 "name"=>"Test name",
 "industry"=>"Test industry",
 "email"=>"test@test.com"}}
```

As you can see, a4 comes from a check box that yields an array of values. My proposed solution to this point is this:

```
params.require(:survey_answer).permit(:a1, :a2, :a3, :a7, :name, :email, :industry, :a4 => [], :a5, :a6)
```

Unfortunately no matter how I refactor I still get to the same point.

Comment: Did you try this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879356/strong-parameters-not-accepting-array/17931946#17931946

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
params.require(:survey_answer).permit(:a1, :a2, :a3, :a7, :name, :email, :industry, {:a4 => []}, :a5, :a6)
```

Comment: Thanks. I still get forbidden access though.

Answer (score 0):

try this it worked for me

```
params.require(:survey_answer).permit(:a1, :a2, :a3, :a7, :name, :email, :industry, :a5, :a6, a4: [])
```

just shift your array type argument at the end.
I hope this will work.