# What is the returned variable for collection_check_boxes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, form-for

Environment: Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.1, Windows 8.1

I set up a collection_check_box in my edit view.  It works in the view, in that it is checked if the model instance's variable is true and is not checked if it is false.  I can check it or uncheck it manually.

But, when I go to the controller#update action, I cannot find any hint of the result.  Params does not have it.  The instance doesn't have it, because it is a HABTM relationship, which makes sense because this is a collection_check_box...

So, given this view, what do I do in controller#update to actually implement the update?  I only need to know where the result is returned and can handle it from there...

View follows.  Case in point is @device.role_ids

```
<%= simple_form_for @device,
                    defaults: {label: false},
                    html: {class: 'form-vertical'},
                    wrapper: :vertical_form,
                    wrapper_mappings: {
                            check_boxes: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
                            radio_buttons: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
                            file: :vertical_file_input,
                            boolean: :vertical_boolean
                    } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, disabled: true, label: "Device name is:", required: false %>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:role_ids, Role.where(name: "admin"), :id, :name) do |b|
      b.label(:"data-value" => b.value) { b.check_box + " Administrator?" }
    end %>
    <%= f.input :chg_pwd, as: :boolean,
                checked_value: "true", unchecked_value: "false",
                inline_label: "Generate new password?" %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I found the following error message in the log:

> unpermitted parameters: role_ids

That surprised me because I had role_ids in permitted parameters list:

```
params.require(:device).permit( ... :role_ids)
```

However, I needed to update it to be:

```
params.require(:device).permit( ... :role_ids => [])
```

Reference SO answer [17879356](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879356/strong-parameters-not-accepting-array)

Note that the ellipses in the above code signifies other parameters that I deleted from this message.